# Send FCM Push notifcations to specific devices in android app using MySQL query as identification from a PHP script

Tags: php, android, mysql, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send FCM push notifications in specific android users only using their token saved in mysql database as identification. here's my current progress

**PHP Script Snippet Code: Report_Status.php (File 1)**

```
//Gets the token of every user and sends it to Push_User_Notification.php 
while ($User_Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Retrieve_User, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $User_Token = $User_Row['User_Token'];
            include "../Android_Scripts/Notifications/Push_User_Notification.php";
            $message = "Your Report has been approved! Please wait for the fire fighters to respond!";
            send_notification($User_Token, $message);
        }
```

**PHP code for File 2: Push_User_Notification.php**

```
<?php  //Send FCM push notifications process
include_once("../../System_Connector.php");

function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message
        );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = API_ACCESS_KEY',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);           
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
}

?>
```

**Problem:**

The page is always stuck in `Report_Status.php` every time I ran the
script. It is supposed to go in `Push_User_Notification` and return to `Report_Status` once the process is done. Am I wrong in the implementation of calling the
`Push_User_Notification.php` or the receiving parameters to
`Push_User_Notification.php`?

**P.S.**

Here's my full source code of `Report_Status.php` in case anyone wants to check it: [Report_Status.php](https://pastebin.com/Pbc2cRKY)

Comment: What do you mean by stuck. Is it supposed to go to a different page.

Comment: @MohammadC yes, but it does not going to a different page.

Comment: Do you get any error messages on the page.

Comment: Also your `$message` should look something like this `$message = array('title' => 'This is a title.', 'body' => 'Here is a message.');`

Comment: @MohammadC none. I tried before my code and it's working perfectly. the only problem before is my SQL query, instead of sending it to specific device/s it sends to all users who had a token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you may be having is that you are sending a lot of notifications to several devices in short amount of time. I think it might be being picked up as spaming. My suggestion is sending one notification to multiple devices.

Try changing your code in report_status.php to this.

```
include "../Android_Scripts/Notifications/Push_User_Notification.php";
$message = "Your Report has been approved! Please wait for the fire fighters to respond!";
while ($User_Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Retrieve_User, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $User_Token[] = $User_Row['User_Token'];
}
$tokens = implode(",", $User_Token);
send_notification($tokens, $message);
```

the idea is that you will collect the user tokens in `$User_Token[]` array. Then you would comma seperate the tokens and send the message once to all the devices that associate to the tokens. FCM allows you to send to multiple tokens in one go.

**updated**

`$User_Token` needs to be an array. so remove the implode. That was my mistake.

Secondly the `$message` needs to be in the following format.

```
$message = array(
    'title' => 'This is a title.',
    'body' => 'Here is a message.'
);
```

Also another thing to note is that there are 2 types of messages you can send using FCM. Notification Messages or Data Messages. Read more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

I dont know if your app is handling the receipt of messages (i dont know if you have implemented `onMessageRecieve` method) so i would probably suggest making a small change to the `$fields` array in `send_notification` function. Adding the notification field allows android to handle notifications automatically if your app is in the background. So make sure you app is in the background when testing. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

```
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $tokens,
    'data' => $message,
    'notification' => $message
);
```

So try the code below. I have tried and tested. It works for me. If it does not work. In `send_notification` function echo $result to get the error message. `echo $result = curl_exec($ch);` Then we can work from there to see what is wrong. You can see what the errors mean  here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes

```
include "../Android_Scripts/Notifications/Push_User_Notification.php";
$message = array(
    'title' => 'Report Approved',
    'body' => 'Your Report has been approved! Please wait for the fire fighters to respond!'
);
while ($User_Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Retrieve_User, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $User_Token[] = $User_Row['User_Token'];
}
send_notification($User_Token, $message);
```

Comment: Thanks. the logic of your code improves the flow of the program, but it still not sending any notifications. what seems to be the problem (new problem /old problem)? But it sucessfully retrieved the tokens when I print the `$tokens` array.

Comment: BTW here's my full source code of `Report_Status.php` in case you want to checl: [Report_Status.php](https://pastebin.com/Pbc2cRKY)

Comment: Okay. I will try and take a look when i get time.

Comment: @Denzell Hey, Check my updated section of my answer. If the code does not work then make sure to echo the error and post it here.

Comment: [Output of `echo $result = curl_exec($ch);`](https://imgur.com/a/vz3DeSa) Yes it works now, but there's one more problem. It is successfully received by the devices now but it crashes their application when the device received the notification. it does not display any notification but it crashes the app everytime I triggered the PHP script `Push_User_Notification.php`

Comment: Okay. Start a new question and post the android code that handles your notifications. Also what changes did you make to get it to work. Post link of the question here so i can find it if someone has not been able to fix it for you. You will probably need to connect your phone to android studio in debugging mode to see and check the logs to see what errors you are getting. That will help without that it maybe difficult to find out whats going wrong. Post those logs with your question.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the title in the message array :D